# Python Infinite loop for raw_input (conversation simulator)

Tags: python, loops, infinite, raw-input

In my code, my goal is to have a code that lets you talk to something. I've been doing:

```
one = True
two = False
three = False

typed_input = raw_input("Type here: ")
    #first
if one == True and two == False and three == False:
    if typed_input == "blah":
        do something
        typed_input = raw_input("Type here: ")
        one = False
        two = True
        three = False

    elif "the" in typed_input:
        do something else
        typed_input = raw_input("Type here: ")
        one = False
        two = True
        three = False
```

^ repeat for 2 and 3 ^

how do I get a infinite loop?

Comment: research while loops. Then think about 'while True: #codecode'

Comment: That was helpful. I used it and it works. Thak you!